# laravel import multiple csv to database

Tags: laravel, laravel-excel

I'm using SpartnerNL/Laravel-Excel and I'm trying to import multiple csv files to database.

Controller:

```
public function importStatement(Request $request) 
    {
        foreach ($request->file('file') as $file) {
        Excel::import(new StatementsImport, $file);
        }
               
        return back();
    }
```

I tried importing single csv file and it worked using:

```
public function importStatement(Request $request) 
    {
        Excel::import(new StatementsImport, $file);

        return back();
    }
```

My problem is when I'm importing multiple csv files.

Blade:

```
<form action="{{ route('admin.statements.importStatement') }}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
{{ csrf_field() }}
     <div class="p-6 text-center">
          <input id="file" type="file" accept=".csv, application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet, application/vnd.ms-excel" multiple name="file">
          <button type="submit" >Import</button>
     </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've solved my problem by following the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72657301/how-to-import-multiple-excel-files-in-laravel-using-laravel-excel?rq=2):

I edited my blade to:

```
<form action="{{ route('admin.statements.importStatement') }}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
{{ csrf_field() }}
     <div class="p-6 text-center">
          <input id="file" type="file" accept=".csv, application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet, application/vnd.ms-excel" multiple name="file[]">
          <button type="submit" >Import</button>
     </div>
</form>
```